# Continuity and density.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Question: Let $Y, Z$ be real random variables such that $X=(Y, Z)$ has continuous density $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Show that

$$
\mathrm{E}(h(X))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y, z) f(z \mid y) d z f_{Y}(y) d y
$$

where $h: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow[0, \infty)$ is continuous and $f_{Y}$ is density of $Y$.

My attempt: I'm sorry but I don't even know where to begin. It's a tricky question and I'd really appreciate help. Thank you!!

Comment: Recall that $f_{(Y,Z)}(y,z)=f_{Z\mid Y}(z\mid y)\cdot f_Y(y)$.

Comment: If someone could write the answer here separately, I'd be happy to accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the continuity assumption of $h$ and $f$ to get that equality.  In fact, for any measurable function $h$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$ such that $E[h(Y, Z)]$ is finite (i.e., $E[|h(Y, Z)|] < \infty$), we have
\begin{align}
 & E[h(Y, Z)] \\
=& \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}h(y, z)f(y, z)dydz \tag*{(Expectation definition)}\\
=& \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}h(y, z)f(z|y)f_Y(y)dydz \tag*{($f(y,z) = f(z|y)f_Y(y)$)} \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(y, z)f(z|y)dz\right]f_Y(y)dy. \tag*{(Fubini's Theorem)}
\end{align}

Comment: By the way, if you, or anyone else reading this comment, has some time, please check out the two questions on my profile for which I haven't received any answer since days. I'd appreciate your help and I'd be happy to accept and upvote your answers.